# Change Ubuntu 11 scrollbars back to the old style

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 and the new scrollbars in Nautilus, GEdit, etc. are driving me insane! How do I go back to the old (Ubuntu 10.10 and earlier) scrollbars?

In the Natty Nautilus you can't actually see a scrollbar normally. Instead you mouse over to where it *should* be (to the left of the border) and then it appears, *but* it doesn't appear under the mouse pointer! Instead it appears to the side (to the right of the border), so starting to scroll is now a fairly involved mouse manoeuvre. I don't know what UX genius came up with this, but I want none of it.

Comment: @BlueRaja: It's not as bad as this makes it out to be, although it could use some ironing out. The grab target activating at the same time the floating grab handle activates is frustrating. Otherwise, the scroll location actually is visible and the grab handle is usable anywhere in the range of the current scroll area.

Comment: I for one think it is GREAT! You no longer have to worry as to where the scroll bar is. Sometimes when you have pages of text, firefox et al. make the scrollbar so tiny that it's hard to grab it. Here you can easily grab it by just moving to the right, and it's the same size no matter how much text.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[This site](http://tips4linux.com/disable-the-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu-1104/) mentions a way to do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar
sudo su
echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
```

A system restart required

---

It's also possible to run:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar
echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
```

Scrollbars instantly appeared! "sudo -i" puts the whole terminal window into an interactive root environment, so you only have to enter your password once. "sudo su" appears to do the same thing.

Comment: I found that just removing the overlay-scrollbar package is enough to get rid of them.

Comment: Great, thank you! Just removing `overlay-scorllbar` was not enough in my case, I had to do the other step as well.

Comment: Y U USE SUDO SU?

Comment: Presumably the `sudo su` was done to then do the echo with redirection to a root-only file.  An alterantive is `echo LIBwhatever | sudo tee /etc/X11/whatever`, which avoids using the shell redirection and sidesteps the need for `su`.

Comment: Thanks for this as it was driving me absolutely mad, although I find the need for a restart very 'Windows'-ish.

Answer (score 23):

The easy way is to open Synaptic Package manager, scroll down to Liboverlay_scrollbar then mark it for complete removal and then Apply. Once Synaptic finishes, close it out and the old Gnome scrollbar will b be restored.

**Edit:** Command-line version:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge 'liboverlay-scrollbar-*'
#single quotes avoid shell glob-expansion
```

Comment: Great, that works and it's even simpler. Thanks! I've added the command line equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Did anyone mention restarting your machine afterwards? Just restarting Nautilus won't do it.

From [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-in.html):

> So, for everyone searching for this, here's how to disable the overlay
>   scrollbars in Ubuntu 11.04. Simply open a terminal and copy/paste the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo su
> echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
> ```
>
> Then restart your computer.